# Showing G is 2-connected if $\deg(u) + \deg(v) \ge n $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph of order $n \ge 3$ such that $\deg(u) + \deg(v) \ge n $ for every non-adjacent pair of vertices $u,v$ of $G$. Show that $G$ is 2-connected by showing that:
>
> i) $G$ is connected, and
>
> ii) $G$ has no cut vertices.

I know for part ii) that $G$ is 2-connected if and only if $G$ is connected with order at least 3 and contains no cut vertices. However, I'm unsure of how to use the condition  $\deg(u) + \deg(v) \ge n $ to show that $G$ is connected, and that it features no cut vertices.

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, assume $G$ is not connected. Then it has $c\geq2$ connected components $G_1,...,G_c$, such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{c}|G_i|=n$$

$|G_i|$ is the order of component $G_i$.

Now take $v_1 \in G_i$ and $v_2 \in G_j$. The corresponding degrees are $d(v_1)\leq|G_i|-1$ and $d(v_1)\leq|G_j|-1$. Therefore, we should have

$$d(v_1)+d(v_2)\leq |G_i|+|G_j|-2 <n$$

However, Knowing $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not adjacent, $d(v_1)+d(v_2)\geq n$. So, we get a contradiction and $G$ should be connected.

For the second part, a similar approach is taken. First assume that $G$ has a cut vertex $v_c$. Delete it and you are left with more than two components. Take two arbitrary components and find a vertex with maximum degree in them. Then, if you add their degrees, plus a possible connection to $v_c$, you would still be $1$ unit shy to get $n$.